# google captcha always fails with no error code

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, recaptcha

added reCAPTCHA v2 API to web pages and I cannot get it to work. I have configured the keys as added the captcha, in html pages

```
    <!-- Google reCAPTCHA -->
    <script th:src="@{https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js}"></script>
```

and then the `div` element

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></div>
```

On server side (using Spring)

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/contact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public Callable<String> contactQuery(final @ModelAttribute("contact") @Valid ContactForm contactForm,
      final @RequestParam("g-recaptcha-response") String captchaResponse, final BindingResult bindingResult,
      final Model model) {
   .....
  }
```

And then in a separate class

```
@Service
public class ReCaptchaResponseVerfier {

  @Resource
  private Environment environment;

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReCaptchaResponseVerfier.class);

  @Async
  public Future<GoogleCaptchaResponseData> isCaptchaResponseValid(String captchaResponse) throws InterruptedException,
      ExecutionException {

    LOGGER.debug(" Validating captcha {}", captchaResponse);

    if (captchaResponse.isEmpty()) {
      GoogleCaptchaResponseData response = new GoogleCaptchaResponseData();
      response.setSuccess(false);
      response.setErrorCodes("The \"I am not a robot\" genie says you didn't verify, please do so.");
      return new AsyncResult<GoogleCaptchaResponseData>(response);
    }

    AsyncRestTemplate restTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate();

    Map<String, String> uriVariables = new HashMap<String, String>();


    ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<GoogleCaptchaResponseData>> futureResponse = restTemplate.postForEntity(
        "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify", buildCaptachRequest(captchaResponse),
        GoogleCaptchaResponseData.class);

    GoogleCaptchaResponseData response;
    response = futureResponse.get().getBody();

    return new AsyncResult<GoogleCaptchaResponseData>(response);

  }

  private HttpEntity<GoogleCaptchaRequestData> buildCaptachRequest(String captchaResponse) {
    GoogleCaptchaRequestData request = new GoogleCaptchaRequestData();

    request.setResponse(captchaResponse);
    request.setSecret(environment.getProperty("google.recaptcha.secret"));

    return new HttpEntity<GoogleCaptchaRequestData>(request);
  }
```

However, I always get success : false response even if the captcha matches on the page.

Comment: The problem was in request, on the documentation it mentioned to send a POST request, while on the page where to sign up for the keys is says GET request. Changed to GET request and it works now.

Comment: please provide GoogleCaptchaResponseData source

Comment: Its sorted. Problem was in documentarion. Says post in one place and get in another. GET is the correct method.

Comment: I am trying to implement recaptcha server validation. If you can provide your code it would be helpful for mt

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anadimisra/a8ca496b8a9cbce89608 posted here